# How to add several ports to FirewallException in Wix?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, custom-action

I use property PORTS to pass some http ports to my installation.
Then these ports will be stored into init file and used by the application.
I need to add these ports to FirewallException?
But following code does not work:

```
<Component Id="fwException" Guid="MyGUID">
   <Condition>Privileged</Condition>
   <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Company\[ProductName]">
      <RegistryValue Name="fwException" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" Type="integer" />
   </RegistryKey>

   <fire:FirewallException Id="My_Ports" Name="My Node.exe" Profile="domain" Port="[PORTS]" Protocol="tcp" Scope="localSubnet"/>
</Component>
```

How to add several ports to FirewallException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary**

In WIX 3.9 (and earlier), the [FirewallExtension](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/firewall/firewallexception.html) only supports a single integer for the `Port` attribute. The `Port` attribute supports [Formatted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) values, but the result of the formatting must still be a single integer.  In your case `[PORTS]` must evaluate to a single integer.

If the `Port` attribute is set to 'Not a number', you would typically see this error in the installation log:

```
SchedFirewallException:  Error 0x80070057: failed to parse record field: 3 as number: Not a number
```

From @Sean's comment, multiple ports should work in WIX 3.10.  See http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4206/ for details of the feature request.

**Workaround for WIX 3.9 and Earlier**

It is possible to work around this restriction by using `FirewallExtension` delcarations:

```
<Component Id="fwException" Guid="-- YOUR GUID --">
  <Condition>Privileged</Condition>
  <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Company\[ProductName]">
  <RegistryValue Name="fwException" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" Type="integer" />
  </RegistryKey>

  <fire:FirewallException Id="My_Port1" Name="My Node.exe" Profile="domain" Port="[PORT1]" Protocol="tcp" Scope="localSubnet"/>
  <fire:FirewallException Id="My_Port2" Name="My Node.exe" Profile="domain" Port="[PORT2]" Protocol="tcp" Scope="localSubnet"/>
</Component>
```

If you need a variable number of ports (up to a pre-defined maximum limit) you could try 1 firewall extension per component with a condition on each component:

```
<Component Id="fwException1" Guid="-- YOUR GUID --">
  <Condition>Privileged AND PORT1</Condition>
  <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Company\[ProductName]">
  <RegistryValue Name="fwException1" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" Type="integer" />
  </RegistryKey>

  <fire:FirewallException Id="My_Port1" Name="My Node.exe" Profile="domain" Port="[PORT1]" Protocol="tcp" Scope="localSubnet"/>
</Component>

<Component Id="fwException2" Guid="-- YOUR GUID --">
  <Condition>Privileged AND PORT2</Condition>
  <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Company\[ProductName]">
  <RegistryValue Name="fwException2" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" Type="integer" />
  </RegistryKey>

  <fire:FirewallException Id="My_Port2" Name="My Node.exe" Profile="domain" Port="[PORT2]" Protocol="tcp" Scope="localSubnet"/>
</Component>
```

From the command line you would specify multiple ports as: `PORT1=7071`, `PORT2=7072`, and so on.  How suitable this is depends on the maximum number of ports you need to specify.

Comment: Is it possible to create PORTX properties dynamically? I do not know the number of ports that will be specified by user during installation.

Comment: I have updated the answer in response to your comment.

Comment: In my case user will pass only one property PORTS with comma separated ports - PORTS=7071,7072,7073,...

Comment: 4206 has actually been fixed in v3.10 ([pull request](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/pull/132))